# Howto reach logback.xml in an Eclipse RCP plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, logback

I created an Eclipse RCP "Hello World"-Plugin, it's running and showing me the main window, then I created a second plugin called "logging" with the logback libraries and added this logging-plugin as a dependency to the main plugin.

The main plugin now knows the logger-classes, and I can use them, but how do I reach the "logback.xml"-file from the main plugin? This file is stored in the "resources"-folder in the logging-plugin.

```
-mainplugin   <---knows logging classes, but not reaching logback.xml
-logging
|-libs 
|-resources
  |-logback.xml
```

Comment: Why does the main plug-in need to know about logback.xml?  Doesn't "logging" have methods to write to logback.xml?  It seems to me that the main plug-in should call "logging" methods.

Comment: I use the loggin-plugin also to log some events happening in the main plugin, so this classes need the logback.xml to react on setup levels and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*logback.xml* is a configuration file for your logging, the one where you set log level ect. ... right? In this case it belongs to the mainplugin, not to the logging plugin (which would only expose the methods of the jar file in the libs folder).

Like this:

```
-mainplugin
|-resources
  |-logback.xml
-logging
|-libs
```

In order to work you would have to set buddy policies in your plugins and *lockback.xml* have to be in the classpath (!). This is required to allow the logging plugin to find the lockback.xml inside your plugin without to have a direct dependency.

in the MANIFEST.MF of the logging plugin you would have to add:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered
```

In the MANIFEST.MF of your mainplugin you would have to add:

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: org.logplugin.id
```

with `org.logplugin.id` being the id of your logging plugin.

For more information: http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/

Comment: Ah, allright, so I have to put the configuration files in the main plugin? Is it the same with hibernate? I mean should hibernate.cfg.xml also be in the main plugin? Because it makes no sense for me, I got a persistance-plugin, but the configfile has to be in the main plugin that uses the persistance plugin. But thank you for the hint, I'll try it on Monday when I'm back at work...

Comment: Normal workflow is to create one plugin for the library you would use. The sole purpose of this plugin is to make the API availible, you do not include any application specific code here. This library plugin you can reuse in other projects. Your main plugin(s) then use the library. You can see this library plugin as simple jar file ... you would not place the configuration file inside the library jar, would you?

Comment: Well... but the problem is, if I want to use logging in a third plugin I need a second logback.xml, and so on... I can't imagine this is the right way to solve this...

Comment: Of course you can create a library plugin to hold the jar and a second "logging" plugin with a bunch of logging methods and the configuration files. Other plugins then yould depend on this logging plugin and call the methods from it.

Answer (score 0):

A more introductory, including another two approaches, is described at http://devblog.virtage.com/2012/07/logback-and-eclipse-attaching-logback-xml/.

Comment: link broken, you should have added a short overview of the article